Is there a current alternative to MediaWiki's "Counter" extension?
I'm using MediaWiki with the "Semantic MediaWiki" extension.  I would like to be able to use a command to increase a tally by whatever amount I input, such as to list a total price for items entered.  (I imagine it to look something like: {{#AddToTally:MyVariable|123}}.)
I tried the extension "Semantic Result Formats", thinking that its "|format=sum" option would do the trick, but I discovered that multiple identical values assigned to a property get condensed into one.  (For example, three car parts valued at $500, $500, and $1000, would end up being treated as $1500 total, rather than $2000 as I had hoped.)
What few alternative extensions came up in my search attempts were things like arrays, and frankly I find all the math and brackets and special terms impossible to digest.  If I knew the technical jargon for what it is that I seek, my searches might prove more fruitful.
The "Counter" extension seemed like it might be what I needed, but my wiki wouldn't work with it installed, and the extension's page says it's no longer maintained.
Suggestions?

It looks like you need Scribunto and Semantic Scribunto.

You can use a template like this one: https://support.wiki.gg/wiki/Template:Iter
<includeonly>{{#vardefine:varname|ITER_INDEX_{{#if:{{{1|}}}|{{{1}}}|default}}<!-- end vardefine -->}}<!--

main logic
-->{{#vardefineecho:{{#var:varname}}|
  {{#expr:
    {{#ifeq:{{lc:{{{reset|}}}<!-- end lc -->}}
            |yes
            |0
            |{{#var:{{#var:varname}}|0}}
    <!-- end ifeq -->}} + {{#if:{{{get|}}}|0|1}}
  <!-- end expr -->}}
<!-- end vde -->}}</includeonly><noinclude>{{documentation}}
[[Category:Templates]]</noinclude>

See documentation at the link above
You'd want to amend it slightly so that instead of increasing by 1 each time it increments by a parameter, but the idea is mostly the same
